# context.Wait<T>() and context.Wait() get mixed up

Tags: c#, botframework

Something has been happening to the Bot Framework that is giving more grief than smiles.

Take the following example:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{            
    _userName    = context.FindUserName();
    _packageId   = context.FindPackageId();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_packageId))
    {
        context.Call(new ConfirmPackageIdResuse(_packageId), AfterConfirmIdReuseAsync);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Call(new AskForPackageIdDialog(), DisplayPackageStatusAsync);
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This startup task is within an **class ObtainPackageIdDialog : IDialog** that is called from multiple methods in an underlying LuisDialog. a *packageId* is utilized for tracking a package, changing address, changing delivery time etc.

The flow goes like this:

- LuisDialog does a CALL to obtain package id
- ObtainPackageId either

  - Calls ConfirmPackageResue
  - Calls AskForPackageIdDialog

Now, if there is a packageId within the context (stored in *ConversationData*), then the bot will ask the user if he would like to use that (**ConfirmPackageIdReuse**) or if he'd like to enter a new package Id (**AskForPackageIdDialog**).

The latter looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class AskForPackageIdDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Type in the package id:");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }


    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var candidate = (await result).Text;
        var validator = WebApiApplication.IoCResolver.GetInstance<IPackageValidator>();

        if(validator.IsValidId(candidate))
        {
            context.SetPackageId(candidate);
            context.Done(candidate);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Driving me nuts 1

The *MessageReceivedAsync()* inside **AskForPackageIdDialog** executes immediately, without any waits. No exceptions to be found.

#### Driving me nuts 2

Since the *MessageReceivedAsync()* executes immediately, there is no valid packageId from the result, so the **else** statement kicks in. Problem is, it's no longer in **AskForPackageIdDialog** but in the class that called it one step up on the dialog stack.

#### Driving me nuts 3

As you see from the declaration of **AskForPackageIdDialog** it is an *IDialog<string>* so the dialog below is resumed in the following method:

```
private async Task DisplayPackageStatusAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
```

However, here, it crashes, stating that it received an **IAwaitable<MessageActivity>** even though the closing dialog class if of type IDialog.

I have read the documentation on the bot framework over and over, and I cannot see why this is failing for me. Any input on what I might be doing wrong will be appreciated.

> Observation 
>   It DOES look like the underlying LUISDialog might be to blame here, I Can tell that it does fill out activity.text, and this is present 2 dialogs up on the stack. The property is get/set, and I've tried to clear it by setting it explicitly to string.Empty, but it still arrives 2 stacks up with the activity text that made the Intent hit.

I have a theory that **context.Call()** seems to be doing a **context.Forward()** from my LUIS dialog, as the activity.Text has the original user text. This then throws off my other dialogs by invoking MessageReceivedAsync at once. IF that is the case, how do you properly reset the context.Activity before doing a call?

### Last, the question

Based on the above, and my theory, this *could* explain why I get mixed responses from **context.Call<string>()** and **context.Call()**. Could someone please confirm to me that this is the case? During developement, I see a whole lot of exceptions about the wrong type of **IAwaitable** with no apparent explanation.

I found a question here on StackOverflow that indicates the bot framework now automatically uses the last used *context.Wait* method in order to avoid too much boilerplate, but I believe this can be the root of my grief right now, and surely will lead to a whole lot of confusion.

**Requested in comments: **

```
   [Serializable]
    public class LuisRoot : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public LuisRoot(ISettingsReader settings)
            : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(settings["luis.modelid"], settings["luis.subscriptionkey"])))
        {            
        }


[LuisIntent("None")]
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Oh, I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you just said!");
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}

    [LuisIntent("Track package")]
    public async Task TrackPackageAsync(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;            
        context.ConversationData.SetValue("LuisResult", result);
        context.Call(new GetPackageId(), AfterPackageIdForTrackingStatus);            
    }


    private async Task AfterPackageIdForTrackingStatus(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var packageId = await result;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(packageId))
        {
            context.Call<object>(new DisplayPackageStatus(packageId), AfterDisplayPackageStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry, but I cannot help you without a valid tracking Id.");                
        }            
    }
```

** And finally, the MessagesController.Post()**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog()); 
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Pedro, can you add more details about your LuisDialog first?

Comment: Please share the code for the LuisDialog, and the MessagesController.Post method.  Have you tried changing IAwaitable<string> to IAwaitable<MessageActivity> ?

Comment: I added the relevant methods from LuisDialog. Also posted the MessagesController.Post() method, which calls the LuisDialog after asking for a name. This part works with no problems, so RootDialog() is not shown for brevity.

Comment: I don't believe .StartAsync is the place to make a context.Call().  Whatever code had loaded the dialog containing the StartAsync method should contain the branching logic.

Comment: Driving me nuts 1:
This is by design.  context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync) doesn't mean: "stop the code here, and wait" but rather, "resume here when this dialog is reloaded with a new message from the user in the context of this conversation".

Comment: Driving me nuts 2:
I'm having a difficult time following the flow, without also seeing the rest of the code. I tried to duplicate your scenerio, but there's just too much missing.  If you can share a simplified version of your issue in a github repo, or something, I'll take a look.  Based on what you've shown so far, your scenario is entirely doable.